# Canvas: Understanding globalCompositeOperation to erase part of an image overlay

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to wrap my head around the [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property by attempting to combine these two examples:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9113vdtq/1/) and [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgxyrB).

The former is using `destination-out`and the latter is using `source-over`.  Would it be possible to use the fiery cursor in the Codepen, but also have it remove the portion of the overlay fill that the user clicks on, as in the Fiddle?

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  I can combine the demos on Codepen to use the same methods if necessary.

Relevant Fiddle code:

```
function drawDot(mouseX,mouseY){
    bridgeCanvas.beginPath();
    bridgeCanvas.arc(mouseX, mouseY, brushRadius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
    bridgeCanvas.fillStyle = '#000';
    bridgeCanvas.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    bridgeCanvas.fill();
}
```

Relevant Codepen code:

```
Fire.prototype.clearCanvas = function(){
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba( 15, 5, 2, 1 )";
    this.ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    this.ctx.rect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.pattern;
    this.ctx.fill();/**/
}
```

Comment: first draw the erase function, then draw the flame on it (think of it has layers in PS)

Comment: Thank you for the note about Photoshop layers.  That's a good way to look at it.  But I'm struggling because the fiery cursor seems to require a full canvas redraw (i.e. fill) each refresh, does it not?  How do I get around that when they're using two different composite methods?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that your eraser one is actually using a CSS background-image, I thought it was already complete... So what you need is to use a second off-screen canvas, draw only the erase on it, then on the visible canvas, draw the bg, then the erased offscreen canvas, then the flame.

Comment: My brain was not prepared for that answer.  I... uhhh... will try!  I think the gist of what you're saying is that I need to use two canvases instead of trying to combine them into one.  I am still uncertain if that will work because the fiery cursor canvas seems to require a background redraw, which would just overlap anything I did on the eraser canvas, but I will defer to your wisdom and attempt it.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have 2 canvases. Your eraser will use only the offscreen one, and update only it. Then on the visible one, for each frame, you'll first draw the background, using `drawImage(bg)`, then the offscreen canvas, also using drawImage(offScreen_canvas), and finally let the fiery cursor do what it has to do on the resulting image. Just remember to reset the gCO to `source-over` at every starting frame (before drawing the bg)

Comment: I want to thank you so much, Kaiido, for your guidance.  It makes perfect sense in my brain, but my execution is all off.  This is still completely eluding me a week later.  I need a practical example to fully grasp what I'm doing wrong.  I am beginning a bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, you'll have to divide your code in at least two parts.
The cropper function uses `"destination-out"` compositing operation to remove the already drawn pixels of the canvas where the new ones should be drawn. In your version, it uses a background-image, and once the foreground pixels are removed, you can see this background since in the now transparent areas of the canvas.

The flame one in the other hand, uses '"lighter"', `"color-dodge"` and `"soft-light"` blending operations. This will add the colors of both the already there and the new drawn pixels.
At least the first one, if used on a transparent area, will be the same as the default `"source-over"` composite operation. So you need to have the background image drawn onto the canvas to be able to use it in the blending.

For this, you've got to use a second, off-screen canvas, where you will only apply the *eraser* `"destination-out"` operation. Then, on the visible canvas, at each new *eraser* frame, you'll have to draw the background image on your visible canvas, then the *eraser* one, with the holes, and finally the *blending* one, which will mix all together.

Here is a quick code dump, where I rewrote a bit the eraser, and modified the Fire one, in order to make our main function handles both events and animation loop.

```js
function MainDrawing(){
  this.canvas = document.getElementById('main');
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.background = new Image();
  this.background.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg"
  this.eraser = new Eraser(this.canvas);
  this.fire = new Fire(this.canvas);
  this.attachEvents();
  }
MainDrawing.prototype = {
   anim: function(){
     if(this.stopped)
        return;
     this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
     this.ctx.drawImage(this.background, 0,0);
     this.ctx.drawImage(this.eraser.canvas, 0,0);
     this.fire.run();
     requestAnimationFrame(this.anim.bind(this));
     },
  stop: function(){
      this.stopped = true;
    },
  attachEvents: function(){
    var mouseDown = false;
 this.canvas.onmousedown = function(){
  mouseDown = true;
  };
 this.canvas.onmouseup = function(){
  mouseDown = false;
  };
    this.canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
     if(mouseDown){
      this.eraser.handleClick(e);
      }
     this.fire.updateMouse(e);
     }.bind(this);
    }
 };

function Eraser(canvas){
  this.main = canvas;
  this.canvas = canvas.cloneNode();
  var ctx = this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
   };
  this.img.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-2013.jpg";
  this.getRect();
}
Eraser.prototype = {
  getRect: function(){
      this.rect = this.main.getBoundingClientRect();
    },
  handleClick: function(evt){
    var x = evt.clientX - this.rect.left;
    var y = evt.clientY - this.rect.top;
    this.draw(x,y);
    },
  draw: function(x, y){
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI*2);
    this.ctx.fill();
    }
 };
  

var Fire  = function(canvas){

 this.canvas   = canvas;
 this.ctx    = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

 this.aFires   = [];
 this.aSpark   = [];
 this.aSpark2   = [];



 this.mouse = {
  x : this.canvas.width * .5,
  y : this.canvas.height * .75,
 }

}

Fire.prototype.run = function(){
 
 this.update();
 this.draw();

}
Fire.prototype.start = function(){

 this.bRuning = true;
 this.run();

}
Fire.prototype.stop = function(){

 this.bRuning = false;

}
Fire.prototype.update = function(){

 this.aFires.push( new Flame( this.mouse ) );
 this.aSpark.push( new Spark( this.mouse ) );
 this.aSpark2.push( new Spark( this.mouse ) );



 for (var i = this.aFires.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aFires[i].alive )
   this.aFires[i].update();
  else
   this.aFires.splice( i, 1 );

 }

 for (var i = this.aSpark.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aSpark[i].alive )
   this.aSpark[i].update();
  else
   this.aSpark.splice( i, 1 );

 }


 for (var i = this.aSpark2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  if( this.aSpark2[i].alive )
   this.aSpark2[i].update();
  else
   this.aSpark2.splice( i, 1 );

 }

}

Fire.prototype.draw = function(){

 this.drawHalo();
 
 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";//or lighter or soft-light

 for (var i = this.aFires.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  this.aFires[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }

 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "soft-light";//"soft-light";//"color-dodge";

 for (var i = this.aSpark.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  
  if( ( i % 2 ) === 0 )
   this.aSpark[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }

 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";//"soft-light";//"color-dodge";

 for (var i = this.aSpark2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  this.aSpark2[i].draw( this.ctx );

 }


}

Fire.prototype.updateMouse = function( e ){

 this.mouse.x = e.clientX;
 this.mouse.y = e.clientY;

}


Fire.prototype.drawHalo = function(){

 var r = rand( 300, 350 );
 this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
 this.grd = this.ctx.createRadialGradient( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y,r,this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 0 );
 this.grd.addColorStop(0,"transparent");
 this.grd.addColorStop(1,"rgb( 50, 2, 0 )");
 this.ctx.beginPath();
 this.ctx.arc( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y - 100, r, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 this.ctx.fillStyle= this.grd;
 this.ctx.fill();

}


var Flame = function( mouse ){

 this.cx = mouse.x;
 this.cy = mouse.y;
 this.x = rand( this.cx - 25, this.cx + 25);
 this.y = rand( this.cy - 5, this.cy + 5);
 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;
 this.vy = rand( 1, 3 );
 this.vx = rand( -1, 1 );
 this.r = rand( 30, 40 );
 this.life = rand( 2, 7 );
 this.alive = true;
 this.c = {

  h : Math.floor( rand( 2, 40) ),
  s : 100,
  l : rand( 80, 100 ),
  a : 0,
  ta : rand( 0.8, 0.9 )

 }




}
Flame.prototype.update = function()
{

 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;

 this.y -= this.vy;
 this.vy += 0.08;


 this.x += this.vx;

 if( this.x < this.cx )
  this.vx += 0.2;
 else
  this.vx -= 0.2;




 if(  this.r > 0 )
  this.r -= 0.3;
 
 if(  this.r <= 0 )
  this.r = 0;



 this.life -= 0.12;

 if( this.life <= 0 ){

  this.c.a -= 0.05;

  if( this.c.a <= 0 )
   this.alive = false;

 }else if( this.life > 0 && this.c.a < this.c.ta ){

  this.c.a += .08;

 }

}
Flame.prototype.draw = function( ctx ){

 this.grd1 = ctx.createRadialGradient( this.x, this.y, this.r*3, this.x, this.y, 0 );
 this.grd1.addColorStop( 0.5, "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + (this.c.a/20) + ")" );
 this.grd1.addColorStop( 0, "transparent" );

 this.grd2 = ctx.createRadialGradient( this.x, this.y, this.r, this.x, this.y, 0 );
 this.grd2.addColorStop( 0.5, "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + this.c.a + ")" );
 this.grd2.addColorStop( 0, "transparent" );


 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.r * 3, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 ctx.fillStyle = this.grd1;
 //ctx.fillStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + (this.c.a/20) + ")";
 ctx.fill();


 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI );
 ctx.fillStyle = this.grd2;
 ctx.fill();



 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo( this.lx , this.ly);
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, 1)";
 ctx.lineWidth = rand( 1, 2 );
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

}


var Spark = function( mouse ){

 this.cx = mouse.x;
 this.cy = mouse.y;
 this.x = rand( this.cx -40, this.cx + 40);
 this.y = rand( this.cy, this.cy + 5);
 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;
 this.vy = rand( 1, 3 );
 this.vx = rand( -4, 4 );
 this.r = rand( 0, 1 );
 this.life = rand( 4, 8 );
 this.alive = true;
 this.c = {

  h : Math.floor( rand( 2, 40) ),
  s : 100,
  l : rand( 40, 100 ),
  a : rand( 0.8, 0.9 )

 }

}
Spark.prototype.update = function()
{

 this.lx = this.x;
 this.ly = this.y;

 this.y -= this.vy;
 this.x += this.vx;

 if( this.x < this.cx )
  this.vx += 0.2;
 else
  this.vx -= 0.2;

 this.vy += 0.08;
 this.life -= 0.1;

 if( this.life <= 0 ){

  this.c.a -= 0.05;

  if( this.c.a <= 0 )
   this.alive = false;

 }

}
Spark.prototype.draw = function( ctx ){

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo( this.lx , this.ly);
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + (this.c.a / 2) + ")";
 ctx.lineWidth = this.r * 2;
 ctx.lineCap = 'round';
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo( this.lx , this.ly);
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y);
 ctx.strokeStyle = "hsla( " + this.c.h + ", " + this.c.s + "%, " + this.c.l + "%, " + this.c.a + ")";
 ctx.lineWidth = this.r;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();

}

rand = function( min, max ){ return Math.random() * ( max - min) + min; };

var app = new MainDrawing();
app.anim();
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="750" height="465"></canvas>
```

Comment: The bounty is yours (when the timer allows), my friend.  Thank you, truly.  It all seems so obvious now, looking at your code, that I'm not sure why this was tripping me up so much to begin with.  If I may ask, are there any particular resources you prefer for referencing and learning about canvas?

Comment: One last question, if I may:  How would I make this fullscreen and responsive?  Setting the canvas size with CSS is no issue.  But when I use drawImage width/height to cover the canvas, it works fine on initial load, but any browser resizing breaks it and you get an infinite mirror effect.  Using an `addEventHandler('onresize')` function is proving equally fruitless.  Looking at the code, I assumed the Eraser and MainDrawing functions would handle this each redraw.  I seem to be missing something.

Comment: That may be tricky. Basically, you'll have to add an `window.onresize` handler, in which you'll change both `main.canvas` and `eraser.canvas` width/height. But doing so, you'll remove `eraser.canvas` content. So may either want to not resize it but make the drawing function more complex (so that it adjusts the size every time, or, you could create a third canvas, draw the eraser one first on it, resize the eraser canvas then draw the background image on the resized eraser canvas for finally using gCO source-in and draw the temp canvas on it. I'll add it to my answer when I'll get time.

Comment: I think I've got it working responsively save for one piece: when you resize the browser, getRect doesn't update to the new dimensions, therefore the eraser drawing is off by a set amount of pixels from the cursor.  Not sure how to go about updating just that on window.resize

Comment: Yes, I didn't attached it in event listeners, it should simply be called in resize and scroll event. (`eraser.getRect()`). Sorry I didn't have time yet to come back to this.

Comment: No worries, man!  Whenever you get time is fine with me.  You've already taught me more about canvas and layering than I had learned in the last 2 years combined.  I really can't thank you enough.  I'm more just interested in seeing your approach to responsiveness compared to my own at this point.